# How to: Change the background of a png image to match a sample of a piece of cloth?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to change the color of a png.

If I had a png of a sock for example, and 5 different material choices.  How would I program that on click of material choice the back ground of the sock changes to match the material?

Comment: Maybe name the files the hex codes then use the file name as the `background-color` CSS property.  A bit broad as is.

Comment: Hi Victor - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more I can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. *(You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question.)* Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not best as a PHP or HTML question, it's better suited to be a javascript/jQuery question. The reason why is that neither HTML nor PHP can detect a user's click on anything. Once the DOM has been rendered, PHP is finished, and HTML is a markup language more than it is a programming language. *(You could, of course, use forms to accomplish this - but that would be like building a house with only a small screwdriver.)*

So, how to do this?

1. Your sock png should be designed so that when it is overlaid on top of different colored backgrounds, the sock will appear to be a different color. This is something you would do with Photoshop, or GIMP, or etc. *(You probably know this already, but I am including this detail for the benefit of the other readers)*
2. You would use a bit of javascript code/logic to detect which button was clicked, get a value from either its ID or class attribute, and apply the appropriate background.

DEMO:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  let clr = this.id.split('_')[1]; //e.g. red
  $('#sock').removeClass();
  $('#sock').addClass('bg_' + clr);
});
```

```css
#sock{width:100px;height:50px;border:1px solid #ddd;}
#btnDIV{margin-top:15px;}
  button{display:inline-block;margin-right:15px;}

.bg_red{background:tomato;}
.bg_blue{background:lightblue;}
.bg_green{background:palegreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sock"></div>
<div id="btnDIV">
  <button id="btn_blue">Blue</button>
  <button id="btn_red">Red</button>
  <button id="btn_green">Green</button>
</div>
```

<sup>BTW, this answer will undoubtedly be downvoted by other users, but not because it will not work. It will be downvoted for a few possible reasons: (a) I am suggesting a javascript solution when you specifically asked for a PHP solution; (b) Your question is too general so no one should answer it (I disagree, as you can see); (c) Everyone has the privilege of downvoting, and most users exercise that privilege. It is nothing personal and does not impact the usefulness of the answer. If the answer works for you, use it.</sup>